# (TensorFlow) Create Batch in tf.Sesstion

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    random.shuffle(file_list)

    train_set = file_list[:num_samples_per_epoch]
    test_set = file_list[num_samples_per_epoch:]

    batch_train = zip(range(0, len(train_set), BATCH_SIZE),
                      range(BATCH_SIZE, len(train_set) + 1, BATCH_SIZE))


    for start, end in batch_train:
        # make batch
        trX = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_HEIGHT, COLOR_CHANNELS), dtype='float')
        trY = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, len(label_list)), dtype='float')


        image_index = 0
        for i in range(start, end):
            tmpX = load_image(train_set[i])
            print(train_set[i])
            # tmpX = np.reshape(tmpX, ((1,) + tmpX.shape))
            trX[image_index] = tmpX


            tmpY = np.zeros(len(label_list))
            num = int(re.findall('\d+', train_set[i])[0])


            label_index = 0

            for label in label_list:

                if labels_df[label][num] == 1:
                    tmpY[label_index] = 1
                else:
                    tmpY[label_index] = 0

                label_index = label_index + 1

            tmpY = np.reshape(tmpY, len(label_list))
            trY[image_index] = tmpY

            image_index = image_index + 1



        trX = np.reshape(trX, [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, COLOR_CHANNELS])
        trY = np.reshape(trY, [BATCH_SIZE, len(label_list)])


        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]})
        print(sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]}))

        if start % 100 == 0:
            print(i + 1, "th image is trained")

        print(start, " to ", end)
```

And I receive the error below:

> 2017-06-30 21:34:14.159600: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
>   name: GeForce GTX 1080
>   major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.8225
>   pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
>   Total memory: 8.00GiB
>   Free memory: 7.60GiB
>   2017-06-30 21:34:14.159600: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
>   2017-06-30 21:34:14.159600: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
>   2017-06-30 21:34:14.159600: I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\m\windows-gpu\py\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
>   train_35315.tif
>   train_8477.tif
>   train_31936.tif
>   train_23847.tif
>   681134.0
>   4 th image is trained
>   0  to  4
>   train_8335.tif
>   train_27.tif
>   train_18159.tif
>   train_10906.tif
>
> ---
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/planet/ipy2py.py", line 489, in 
>       sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={X: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end]})
>     File "C:\Users\dspl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 789, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)
>     File "C:\Users\dspl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 975, in _run
>       % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
>   ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0, 256, 256, 4) for Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0', which has shape '(4, 256, 256, 4)'
>   Process finished with exit code 1

---

Because my dataset is **.tiff**, I can't use TensorFlow function to read images (such as `tf.WholeFileReader()`, `tf.image.decode_` etc.)

There's no decoder for tiff format as far as I am concerned.

My dataset is too big to allocate list for all images (image size = 256*256, 4 channels, about 40000 images)

I want to read images by batch on each iteration without `tf.image.decode`.

So, I read these images in `Session` using `scipy.io.imread`.

My code passed the first batch but the error below has occurred at the second batch.

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (0, 256, 256, 4) for Tensor 'Placeholder_2:0', which has shape '(4, 256, 256, 4)'

Comment: There is a problem with the batch iterator as it does not pass the next batch to `tf.placeholder()`. You should look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py#L166) function as it explains how to correctly divide data by batches and pass them to the train sequence. If you provided the full code at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) with the appropriate data somewhere to download from, I could elaborate on your problem.

Comment: Hover over the batch-file tag, and question whether it has any relevance to your question.